# Windows server Remote Desktop Services LAGS very with good resources

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-services

RDS services hosted on our windows server 2016 (Hyper-V virtual machine). We use default installation without any clustering/load balancing/etc - merely RDS services and licensing server.

Problem occurs when user count crosses 70-80 sessions (30-40 disconnected sessions and other live users) - start menu doesn't open, new users can't login (new = never logged before) and etc.

First thing we check was our resources - RAM, CPU, disk usage, networking, but all is ok, furthermore, resources utilization very far from 100%. There is no errors in event log.

Also while start menu just doesn't open, explorer works fine: users can navigate through directories and execute programs.

How to fix or debug this problem?

Comment: All that on a single server instance?  I suggest trying to setup a second VM and putting the two in a farm.  My experience has been more the ~40 on a single server kills performance.  Doesn’t matter how much CPU/RAM/etc is assigned.

Comment: About ~50 users per machine kill performance; use a farm. Issues with opening start menu and/or cortana stuff is often seen with redirected/moved profiles and/or changes profile-paths. Use profile vhdx instead.